# DOM element won't get removed on react spring animation

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I'm working on a tutorial and i'm having an issue after adding react spring transition on the checkout page handled by Checkout.js component.

My problem happens when removing items from the basket, the last item on the basket never remove from the DOM even when the array removed the element via reducer.

This was working as expected before adding a transition and animated.div element to checkout component below.

```
import React from "react";
import "./Checkout.css";
import SubTotal from "./SubTotal";
import { useStateValue } from "../StateProvider";
import CheckoutProduct from "./CheckoutProduct";
import shortid from "shortid";

import { useTransition, animated } from "react-spring";

function Checkout() {
  const [{ basket, user }] = useStateValue();

  const getRandomKey = () => {
    return shortid.generate();
  };

  // define transition behaviour
  const transition = useTransition(basket, basket => basket.id, {
    from: { opacity: 0, marginLeft: -100, marginRight: 100 },
    enter: { opacity: 1, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0 }
  });

  return (
    <div className="checkout">
      <div className="checkout__left">
        <img
          className="checkout__ad"
          src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/UK_CCMP/TM/OCC_Amazon1._CB423492668.jpg"
          alt=""
        ></img>
        <div className="checkout__title">
          <h3>Hello, {user?.email}</h3>
          <h2>Your shopping basket</h2>
          {transition.map(({ item, key, props }) => {
            const keyNew = getRandomKey();
            console.log(keyNew + "this is the new key");
            return (
              <animated.div
                key={keyNew}
                style={props}
                className="checkout__product"
              >
                <CheckoutProduct
                  id={item.id}
                  image={item.image}
                  price={item.price}
                  rating={item.rating}
                  title={item.title}
                />
              </animated.div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="checkout__right">
        <h2>SubTotal component</h2>
        <SubTotal />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Checkout;
```

Steps to reproduce:
Add any product to the basket
click on basket icon to go to checkout screen
and try to remove items

Here is the [github repo](https://github.com/JAlonsoHdz/amazon-clone-tutorial) with the tutorial code i'm working on.

Is this problem that requires me to force a render?

Thanks

**Solution:**

Upgraded react spring dependency from 8.0.27 to 9.0.0-rc.3 as suggested by Peter's reply.

And refactored the component as follows us:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Checkout.css";
import SubTotal from "./SubTotal";
import { useStateValue } from "../StateProvider";
import CheckoutProduct from "./CheckoutProduct";
import shortid from "shortid";
import { useTransition, animated } from "react-spring";

function Checkout() {
  const [{ basket, user }] = useStateValue();

  const getRandomKey = () => {
    return shortid.generate();
  };

  // define transition behaviour
  const transition = useTransition(basket, {
    from: { opacity: 0, marginLeft: -100, marginRight: 100 },
    enter: { opacity: 1, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0 }
  });

  return (
    <div className="checkout">
      <div className="checkout__left">
        <img
          className="checkout__ad"
          src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/UK_CCMP/TM/OCC_Amazon1._CB423492668.jpg"
          alt=""
        ></img>
        <div className="checkout__title">
          <h3>Hello, {user?.email}</h3>
          <h2>Your shopping basket</h2>
          {transition((props, item) => {
            const keyNew = getRandomKey();
            return (
              <animated.div style={props}>
                <CheckoutProduct
                  key={keyNew}
                  id={item.id}
                  image={item.image}
                  price={item.price}
                  rating={item.rating}
                  title={item.title}
                />
              </animated.div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="checkout__right">
        <h2>SubTotal component</h2>
        <SubTotal />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Checkout;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with the original key? If you change the key handling strange things can happen.

```
      {transition.map(({ item, key, props }) => {
        return (
          <animated.div
            key={key}
            style={props}
            className="checkout__product"
          >
       ....
```

**Update:**

Also there are some bugs with transition. Try to raise the version number. You can try around 9.0.0-beta.4 or slightly higher. Or you can try 9.0.0-rc.3, but it has a slightly different api. Check the documentation here: https://aleclarson.github.io/react-spring/v9/#Revamped-types

Comment: Thanks for the response, yeah, i tried with basket.id (which is hardcoded and passed via props from home component) but I had the same result. The code works when i remove the transition "wrapper" variable and use directly basket array to map through it but since I want to use react spring transition looks like i have no choice but use it but I feel it's probably no correctly implemented on my side. The reducer logic seems to be doing its part which is removing elements from the basket array.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I upgraded the react spring version as you suggested and refactored slightly the code and now remove function is working! I'm adding my updated component code solution in my post.